# matlab video reader

Tags: matlab

I want to create object of video file. I found that VideoReader is used to create object but it shows error when I try to run it "Undefined Command/Function 'VideoReader'".

Can anyone please tell me how can I install the missing library to run VideoReader.
I am new to Matlab and I didn't find any useful information on net.

Thanks,
Anubhav

Answer (score 2):

It means that your version of MATLAB doesn't have the function 'VideoReader', which only appears after R2010b.

Use mmreader instead, or get a latest version of MATLAB.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/rn/bskfo3t.html#bsmnaxp-1